# Program crashes when entering for loop, using sting arrays

Tags: arrays, string, for-loop

I can't figure out why these lines of code results in my program crashing. The program has no compilation or build errors, and I am not given a reason for the crash.

```
void systemutskrift() {
    int *i = new int;
    string Filnavn[7];
    string overskrift[7];
    Filnavn[0] = "trykk_kokekjele.txt";
    Filnavn[1] = "temperatur_varmtvannstank.txt";
    Filnavn[2] = "nivå_færskvannstank.txt";
    Filnavn[3] = "styrbord_ballast.txt";
    Filnavn[4] = "babord_ballast.txt";
    Filnavn[5] = "nivå_dieseltank.txt";
    Filnavn[6] = "oversikt_oksygentanker.txt";
    overskrift[0] = "Trykk i Kokekjele [BAR]";
    overskrift[1] = "Temperatur i Varmtvannstank [C]";
    overskrift[2] = "Nivå i Ferskvannstank [L]";
    overskrift[3] = "Styrbord Ballasttank [% full]";
    overskrift[4] = "Babord Ballasttank [% full]";
    overskrift[5] = "Nivå i Dieseltank [L]";
    overskrift[6] = "Oversikt Oksygentanker";

    ofstream systemutskrift;
    ifstream innfil;
    string line;
    systemutskrift.open("system.txt");
    for (*i = 0; *i < 7; *i++) {
        systemutskrift << setw(20) << overskrift[*i] << endl;
        systemutskrift << endl;
        innfil.open(Filnavn[*i]);
        if (innfil.is_open()) {
            while (getline(innfil, line)) {
                systemutskrift << line << endl;
            }
        }
        innfil.close();
    }
    systemutskrift.close();
    system("system.txt");
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
}
```

Comment: Please read this and apply it to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you've missed is that the postfix(++) operator has a higher precedence than the dereference(*) operator.

Hence what your program does is that it effectively **increments the pointer first** and then tries to dereference it. This may lead to you trying to access memory that you're not allowed to access hence causing it to crash.

You can fix this problem by using brackets to indicate your preferred order of operations i.e (*i) ++.

Further explanation for the precedence can be found [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-p-p-and-p/)